# Unit testing in Python Pygame for key.get_pressed()

Tags: python, unit-testing, pygame

I am new to python coding and need some help with unit testing. I want to test my modules that move the images location in Pygame based on what the user has pressed. Here are my modules:

```
def moveRight(self):
    self.x = self.x + self.speed

def moveLeft(self):
    self.x = self.x - self.speed
```

Here is where i call these modules:

```
def on_execute(self):

    # While game is running
    while( self._running ):
        pygame.event.pump()

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed() 

        if (keys[K_RIGHT]):
            self.player.moveRight()

        if (keys[K_LEFT]):
            self.player.moveLeft()

        # Use class players function moveUp to move up
        if (keys[K_UP]):
            self.player.moveUp()

        self.on_render()
```

How do i go about testing these? is unit testing different when working with Pygame?

Comment: How do you normally implement unit testing? What have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to abstract `pygame.key.get_pressed()` away, so you can replace it during your tests with something else that returns the fake input we want to test (let's call it mocking).

```
def on_execute(self, key_state_function):

    # While game is running
    while( self._running ):
        pygame.event.pump()

        keys = key_state_function() 

        if (keys[K_RIGHT]):
            self.player.moveRight()

        if (keys[K_LEFT]):
            self.player.moveLeft()

        # Use class players function moveUp to move up
        if (keys[K_UP]):
            self.player.moveUp()

        self.on_render()
```

When running your game, you would pass `pygame.event.get` as argument to `on_execute`, and in your tests, you pass a function that returns whatever you want (a mock).

But since we're using python where, we can also monkey patch `pygame.event.get` (replacing the entire function at runtime).

So in the test we would do something like this:

```
def create_key_mock(pressed_key):
    def helper():
        tmp = [0] * 300
        tmp[pressed_key] = 1
        return tmp
    return helper

pygame.key.get_pressed = create_key_mock(K_RIGHT)
```

and behold, now `pygame.key.get_pressed()` will always tell use the right arrow key is pressed.

Now that you know about this, take a look at the build-in [`mock` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html).